# ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to reshape my pd dataframe with the following function:

```
 ar = ar.pivot(index='Received', columns='Merch Ref', values='acceptance_rate')
```

The dataset looks like:

```
     Merch Ref            Received  acceptance_rate
0           SF 2014-08-28 15:38:00                0
1           SF 2014-08-28 15:44:00                0
2           SF 2014-08-28 16:04:00                0
3           WF 2014-08-28 16:05:00                0
4           WF 2014-08-28 16:07:00                0
5           SF 2014-08-28 16:34:00                0
6           SF 2014-08-28 16:55:00                0
7           BF 2014-08-28 17:59:00                0
8           BF 2014-08-29 15:05:00                0
9           SF 2014-08-29 21:25:00                0
10          SF 2014-08-30 10:29:00                0
...
```

What I'd like to obtain is:

```
                      SF WF BF 
2014-08-28 15:38:00    0  1  0
2014-08-28 15:44:00    0  1  0
2014-08-28 16:04:00    0  0  1
2014-08-28 16:05:00    1  1  0
2014-08-28 16:07:00    0  0  1
2014-08-28 16:34:00    1  1  0
2014-08-28 16:55:00    1  1  0
2014-08-28 17:59:00    0  1  0
2014-08-29 15:05:00    0  0  1
2014-08-29 21:25:00    0  0  1 
2014-08-30 10:29:00    0  1  0
```

However, I get the error:

```
 ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

This is because i have some orders placed at the same time. Is there a way to sum/aggregate these orders ?

Comment: I tried with: ar = ar.pivot_table(ar, values='acceptance_rate', index='Received', columns='Merch Ref') and I got: TypeError: pivot_table() got multiple values for keyword argument 'values'

Comment: `ar.pivot_table(values='acceptance_rate', index='Received', columns='Merch Ref') `

Comment: it worked. great .thanks. You can put it in as answer so that I can close the question

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove duplicate:

```
ar = ar.drop_duplicates(['Received','Merch Ref'])
```

it should work

Comment: ar = ar.drop_duplicates(['Received''])    this was enough for me

Answer (score 1):

As you identified, the error occurs from duplicates in pairs (x, y) for x in `Received` and y in `Merch Ref`.

If you would like to aggregate by `sum` then

```
ar.pivot_table(index='Received', columns='Merch Ref',
               values='acceptance_rate', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

. The default aggregation function is `mean`. That is,

```
ar.pivot_table(index='Received', columns='Merch Ref',
               values='acceptance_rate')
```

, will pivot the table and all entries with the same (x, y) pair will be aggregated with the `np.mean` function.

Remark: I initially received the same error, but after iterating through the (x, y) pairs I didn't find any duplicates. It turns out some of the pairs were of the form (`nan`, `nan`) and were omitted from the iteration process. Thus for other users trying to debug what they believe are unique pairs, consider checking for `nan`s with `pd.isnull` or `pd.notnull`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas.crosstab).

Example:

```py
pd.crosstab(index=ar.Recieved, columns=ar['Merch Ref'], aggfunc='count')
```